# Block only part of a website

Tags: filtering

I have to imagine this is something that gets done in corporate and home networks, but I seem to be choosing bad search terms and haven't found an answer.

What I'm aiming to do is to block certain content from part of a website without blocking the entire domain. That is, I want to block `www.website.com/part_one` but **not** block `www.website.com/part_two`. I know I can't do this with a tool like OpenDNS, but I'd like to find something simple that makes it easy to configure the list. I'm not afraid of command-line tools. I would prefer something that I can do at the LAN level instead of at the device level, if such a thing exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install a (transparent) proxy and configure it to block whatever URLs and patterns you want.  This isn't possible to do at anything below layer 7 (I count DPI as a layer 7 technology), because nothing below that has any idea of the concept of a "URL".